# How to use Azure Web App + Azure DNS for root domain?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to do something pretty simple. I have a domain on godaddy. I want to use Azure Dns to host the domain and connect it to an azure website.

I have it working for www.mydomain.com with the CNAME approach. However I cannot get the root domain, i.e. my domain.com to work with this approach. I tried adding an * A record but that didn't work. I also tried to do CNAME with @ but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to get the root domain to work?  This seems pretty basic but there is no documentation and it is not obvious.

### Thanks

Thanks for feedback on this one!

Comment: Did you do an nslookup to confirm that you were seeing the right records (ie: they had propagated)?

Comment: For the * A record, the * doesn't cover the root.  And Azure DNS won't let you do CNAME root.  The only option left seems to be an A record pointing to virtual IP.  But isn't that virtual IP going to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a DNS 'A' record in Azure DNS to point to the IP address listed for the site in the Web Apps portal (as per the screenshot provided by an earlier answer).  The Web Apps team provide the IP address for precisely this purpose, and they know that they can't change these IP addresses because DNS entries would break.

Note that there's no need to use a wildcard record (name = '*').  You should instead use an A record at the domain apex (name = '@', or if using the Azure Portal you can also leave the name blank).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create the isolated deployment with the static IP, take a look at the Service Environment. The reference [first](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/) and [second](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-how-to-create-an-app-service-environment/).

As you mentioned Azure DNS, i assume that you refer to the Azure DNS service. If so, then it is possible if you have the needed access. [Reference for the DNS zones](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-getstarted-create-dnszone-portal/).

Regarding your question about www and CNAME, there are some nuances that should be taken into account and set up. Please refer to that [post](http://bretstateham.com/10-easy-steps-to-azure-web-site-custom-domains/).

Comment: am trying to get Azure DNS parent and sud domain DNS zones setup to get root domain working.  The link you gave here for www/cname works, but any similiar material for how to using own name servers in registrar? I had posted for this here but not able to make out what I am missing. Could you please give a look of my settings posted here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774313/azure-dns-zone-name-servers-updated-to-domain-registrar-but-unknown-host-even-af

Answer (score 0):

If your hosted your WebAPP in free website plan didn't have any option for adding * A record. You have to Change your web App plan to at least Shared Plan instead of free Plan.[image]

Comment: Thanks -- isn't that Azure IP Address listed there going to change though, and therefore is not safe to use for A records? (i.e. it's a "Virtual IP" not a Static IP)